# PHP MYSQL nested join

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, foreach, nested

```
<?php 
require "includes/dbh_l4d2.php";
$sql = "
SELECT * 
  FROM vpk
  JOIN maps 
    ON vpk.vpk_id = maps.vpk_id";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Website Title</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "assets/css/tek_style.css" /></head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><th>VPK</th><th>MAP</th></tr>
<?php
  $result_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if( $result_num_rows> 0) {
    //while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo '<tr><td id="'.$row["alpha_anchor"].'" rowspan="'.$row["map_count"].'" class="first_row">'.
            '<h3 id="'.$row["anchor"].'">'.$row["vpk_title"].'</h3>'.$row["vpk_file"].'<br>'.
            '<a class="details" href="'.$row[details].'">Details</a>&nbsp;'.
            '<i><a href="'.$row[download].'">Download vpk</a></i>'.
            '</td></tr>';

      for ($i=0; $i < $row["map_count"]-1; $i++) {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$row["map_name"].'></td></tr>';
      }

    }
  }
?>
</table></body></html>
```

Here is the output from the code

[image: wrong output]

This is what I want it to look like

[image: CORRECT OUTPUT]
What needs to be done to make this work correctly??? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: please show result of print_r($result_num_rows) and one suggestion, just select fields from table which you want to use.

Comment: In line ['<a class="details" href="'.$row[details].'">Details</a>&nbsp;'], what is this details, where is it defined??? if it is a column name then it should be in double quote

Comment: print_r($result_num_rows) is 41 (the number of maps associated with the vpk's.

details is a css class, defined in the style sheet which I edited out for this post.

The line prints out, via php, <a class="details" href="THE_URL_OF_THE_DETAIL_PAGE">Details</a>

Answer (score 0):

Your nested loop is getting `map_name` from the same row, not each row of results.

What you can do is use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to combine all the map names into a single row of results, then use `explode()` to split them up when creating the table.

```
<?php 
require "includes/dbh_l4d2.php";
$sql = "SELECT vpk.*, GROUP_CONCAT(maps.map_name) AS map_names 
        FROM vpk 
        INNER JOIN maps ON vpk.vpk_id = maps.vpk_id
        GROUP BY vpk.vpk_id";
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM vpk, maps JOIN vpk ON vpk.vpk_id = maps.vpk_id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Website Title</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "assets/css/tek_style.css" /></head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr><th>VPK</th><th>MAP</th></tr>
    <?php
    $result_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if( $result_num_rows> 0) {
    //while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $map_names = explode(',', $row['map_names']);
        echo '<tr><td id="'.$row["alpha_anchor"].'" rowspan="'.$row["map_count"].'" class="first_row">'.
            '<h3 id="'.$row["anchor"].'">'.$row["vpk_title"].'</h3>'.$row["vpk_file"].'<br>'.
            '<a class="details" href="'.$row[details].'">Details</a>&nbsp;'.
            '<i><a href="'.$row[download].'">Download vpk</a></i>'.
            '</td></tr>';

        foreach ($map_names as $map_name) {
            echo '<tr><td>'.$map_name.'></td></tr>';
        }
    }
}
?>
</table></body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, especially Barmar, thank you for all your help!!! It works! I had to make one small adjustments because the rowspan needed to be increased by one:
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $map_names = explode(',', $row['map_names']);
        $row_map_count = $row["map_count"] + 1;
        echo '<tr><td id="'.$row["alpha_anchor"].'" rowspan="'.$row_map_count.'" class="first_row">'.
            '<h3 id="'.$row["anchor"].'">'.$row["vpk_title"].'</h3>'.$row["vpk_file"].'<br>'.
            '<a class="details" href="'.$row[details].'">Details</a>&nbsp;'.

Comment: You could also put `$map_names[0]` in the first row, and loop through the rest in the `foreach`